# getChildren() add() and add()

Tags: java, javafx-2, addition, get-childitem

why sometimes we use getChildren() add() and other times instead we use add() directly es: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/form.htm

```
Example 4–4 Button
Button btn = new Button("Sign in");
HBox hbBtn = new HBox(10);
hbBtn.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
hbBtn.getChildren().add(btn);
grid.add(hbBtn, 1,`enter code here`
grid.add(userTextField, 1, 1);
Label pw = new Label("Password:");
grid.add(pw, 0, 2);
PasswordField pwBox = new PasswordField();
grid.add(pwBox, 1, 2);)
```

Example 4–3 Controls

```
Text scenetitle = new Text("Welcome");
scenetitle.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.NORMAL, 20));
grid.add(scenetitle, 0, 0, 2, 1);
Label userName = new Label("User Name:");
grid.add(userName, 0, 1);
TextField userTextField = new TextField();
```

Answer (score 1):

Afaik only `GridPane` provides an `add` method directly. This method exists to shorten the required code for adding a child to the and assign the row/column index (and column/row span). You need to assign row/column indices for almost all children of a `GridPane` which is why those methods are useful.

```
gridPane.add(child1, column1, row1);

gridPane.add(child2, column2, row2, columnSpan, rowSpan);
```

is much shorter than

```
GridPane.setColumnIndex(child1, column1);
GridPane.setRowIndex(child1, row1);
gridPane.getChildren().add(child1);

GridPane.setColumnIndex(child2, column2);
GridPane.setRowIndex(child2, row2);
GridPane.setColumnSpan(child2, columnSpan);
GridPane.setRowSpan(child2, rowSpan);
gridPane.getChildren().add(child2);
```

Other layouts such as `VBox` do not provide such a method, since the children are positioned based on the order in the child list and assigning optional layout parameters such as `margin` is done less frequently.

Comment: So we use add instead of getChildren().add() because we don't have, in certain circumstances, the add() method available for some classes, so there are no other evaluations to do besides this

Comment: `GridPane` has a specialized `add` helper method so you can place the child in a specific row or column.  Other containers just add the child at the end.  Doing this with `GridPane` is also allowed, but the child would be placed at (0,0) which is rarely what you want.